# Fabric JS; How to make an object unmovable until the object is "fully" clicked (mouse down and mouse up)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I am wondering if it is possible to make an object unmovable until it is "fully" clicked. At the moment the object is movable as soon as it is selected, which is not great because it can lead to accidental movements. Is it possible to disable all movement of an object until it is fully clicked? i.e. the user clicks the objects and releases the mouse so both onMouseDown and onMouseUp is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FabricJS vs 4.4.0 introduced a new object property called `activeOn`. By default, the value is 'down', meaning that objects are made active on mouse down/touch start. If you change the value to 'up', the object will only be made active after mouse up/touch end. http://fabricjs.com/changelog

```
fabric.Object.prototype.activeOn = "up";
```

Comment: Very nice! Are you a fabricJS contributor?

Comment: No problem. Yes, this feature was one of my recent contributions

Comment: This feature is such a life saver, a small detail but has huge implications for UX

Comment: By the way can I contact you some how (discord, email etc.)? I might have some feedback on how to make fabricJS even better, if you are open for it :)

Comment: Sure, you'll find my email on my github profile (I'd prefer not to share it here).